# Capes and Hoods

Tags: minifigures, accessories

Is it possible to fit both a [cape](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=49486&name=Minifigure,%20Cape%20Cloth,%20Wide%20Shoulders,%20Narrow%20Tapered%20Cape%20-%20Traditional%20Starched%20Fabric&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Body%20Wear%5D#T=C&C=11) and a [hood](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30381&name=Minifigure,%20Headgear%20Hood&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Headgear%5D#T=C) on a single minifigure?

Comment: You could have easily answered this yourself by checking which sets/minifigures your cape comes with under "Known colors' on Bricklink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=ow008) minifigure utilize both of your items:

[image]